# VBscript: EOF/AtEndOfStream not recognised?

Tags: vbscript, emulation, mainframe

I am running macros in a mainframe emulator that read a text file to get the input key for a CICS screen and loop through the pages of the CICS screen outputting to Excel.  Our emulator software has changed from Passport to Bluezone which has required some re-engineering of the proprietary screen logic but has also thrown up some weird errors with VB syntax.  A number of them whilst annoying were easily resolved but my issue now is that I cannot seem to get the script to handle the end of file properly.  Below is a snapshot of the logic that I have tried.  When using the AtEndOfStream logic I get an "Input past end of file" error - when using the EOF logic the script just loops, continually processing the last record on file.  It seems like neither version is recognising the end of the file, the file being used is a simple ASCII notepad that in this case contains a 6-character string, each line terminated with return.  Note that the version 1 logic is exactly the same as it was in the old macro that ran perfectly fine in the Passport Emulator without throwing any errors, also the Bluezone emulator developer guide suggests using the version 2 logic.

Version 1:

```
ForReading = 1
Set objFSObject = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set strFileContents = objFSObject.OpenTextFile(strFile,ForReading)

Do while not strFileContents.AtEndOfStream

  dline = strFileContents.readLine
```

Version 2:

```
Open strFile For Input As #1   

Do While Not EOF(1) 

  Line Input #1, dline
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I have reviewed numerous threads on "Input past end of file" errors and not found a resolution and this is particularly annoying given that it works fine in the old emulator software.

Comment: I'm assuming Version 2 is being done in VB6, not VBScript? One thing you could do (not an answer to your question by any means) is use `ReadAll()` to read the entire file in. I'm curious if that works for you. If so, you could then split by `vbCrLf` to process line by line.

Comment: Thanks for the response - the bottom line is neither option works.  When I get to the end of the file I get an "input past end of file" error.  The only way I have been able to stop the script properly is to stick and arbitrary EOF value at the end of my file and then check for that after the read - I obviously don't want to stick with this solution as it is rubbish.  I have done comparison runs of my macros in both emulators with the exact same input text file and one works and the other does not so I presume that puts the fault somewhere in the new emulator and it's scripting capabilities.